# C++ : Incorrect File Size Calculation WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

here My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("C:\\Windows10.official.16.November.2016.iso",&FindFileData);
    if ( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        cout << "Can't Find the File\n";
    cout << ( ( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh * ( MAXDWORD + 1 ) ) + FindFileData.nFileSizeLow );
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
2300968960
```

but the actual file size is 6.14 GB
so Output should be something like

```
6592774799
```

can anyone help me why?

Comment: Why don't you use GetFileSizeEx instead?

Comment: You need to perform the arithmetic in a 64 bit context. Use a 64 bit literal with the value 2^32.

Comment: `MAXDWORD + 1 == 0`. use `MAXDWORD + 1ULL` instead. but better use `LARGE_INTEGER li = { nFileSizeLow, nFileSizeHigh };` and then use `li.QuadPart`

Comment: Solved using getFileEx using Large_Integer.LowPart

Comment: but why Lowpart, Quadpart and Highpart gives wrong answers

Comment: MAXDWORD + 1ULL gives correct answer too, but why?

Comment: how I say `MAXDWORD + 1 == 0` and `MAXDWORD + 1ULL == 0x100000000` - exist different ?

Comment: may be size difference, a very big size difference and value too? but why msdn documentation prescribes that method which doesn't works with C++, is there something to do with compilers?

Comment: `MAXDWORD + 1ULL` is pretty ugly. What's wrong with the actual value in a 64 bit literal as I said.

Comment: i can't guess how it will implemented.;p

Comment: Because `MAXDWORD + 1 == 0` and `MAXDWORD + 1ULL == 0x100000000`. Because you need to force the use of 64 bit arithmetic rather than 32 bit arithmetic.

Comment: okay, now i understood, Thanks.

Comment: `MAXDWORD + 1ULL is pretty ugly` - agree. and because this I and say - better use `LARGE_INTEGER li = { nFileSizeLow, nFileSizeHigh };` and then use `li.QuadPart ` . be at all better if win32 (like nt) at begin use `LARGE_INTEGER` in `WIN32_FIND_DATA` for file size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is expand at least one part of the expression `( ( FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh * ( MAXDWORD + 1 ) ) + FindFileData.nFileSizeLow )` to 64-bit to prevent 32-bit overflow.

I'm using bit operations here because I think it's more natural for things like this, but the same principle applies:

```
uint32_t hi = 0x12345678, lo = 0x90ABCDEF;
uint64_t hilo = ( static_cast<uint64_t>( hi ) << 32 ) | lo;
```

So casting `hi` to 64-bit will make sure the whole calculation is done in 64-bit.

[Live Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f04fce8089523a)